# PHP stopped working after installing sendmail on raspberry pi

Tags: web-server, php, lighttpd, html5, google-chrome

My PHP is not working after I installed sendmail on the raspberry pi. PHP is still installed. I checked using

```
php -v
```

on the command line. My lighttpd server is just not serving php. I've tried restarting the server and the pi itself. It only serves the html of the webpages, and it serves the pure php pages as a text document. I uninstalled sendmail to no effect.

UPDATE:
So apparently it was because Apache was also installed. After uninstalling, php works when accessing it on the pi, but when I try to access some pages, like a logout script, it just serves the php as a text file.

UPDATE 2:
Okay, apparently the php just isn't working on chrome for mobile. This seems like a serious security issue.

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: There aren't any errors. It just displays the php as text.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall PHP? Report back on what happens after.

Comment: Says it is already installed, although after changing a form method to post it worked, but it still seems like a serious security error.